# How to display multiple trees simultaneously with ete3?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ete3, etetoolkit

I debuted recently on `ete3` (on Python3), and for debugging purposes I would find convenient to display two trees side to side, as in `matplotlib.pyplot.subfig` for instance. However, I found no information about this in the documentation nor on this website (which is quite surprising), and using `tree.show()` always halts the execution of the program.

So yeah, if someone knows how to do this, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to display more one tree image in the same panel with ete3.